# How to transpose columns to rows in SQL or EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, transpose

I have a list of SQL tables(the list can change) that I want to transpose and save it into a c# list with 2 fields(Name and Value).

Ex: table **Addresses**(Id int, DocId int, Type int, StreetName varchar, StreetNo int) -- the other tables will have other datatypes.

```
SELECT Id , DocId, Type , StreetName , StreetNo FROM Addresses WHERE DocId = 2
```

This will result into multiple records that I want to transpose.
[image]
**Q1:** What is the best approach when transposing a table ?

1.SQL transpose. The columns needs to be converted(CAST) but for easy reading :

```
  SELECT  Field, Value FROM 
     ( SELECT Id, DocId, Type, StreetName, StreetNo FROM Addresses WHERE DocId = 2) p 
  UNPIVOT
     (Value FOR Field IN (Id, DocId, Type, StreetName, StreetNo)) AS unpvt
```

2. C# transpose. The tables are send untransposed.

```
            foreach (string tb in Tables)
            {                    
                var results = context.Database.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ tb +" WHERE DocId = 2");
                //Transpose results. 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

creating table

CREATE TABLE yourtable
    ([Country_Code] varchar(3), [1960] varchar(4), [1961] varchar(4), [1962] varchar(4), [2011] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    ([Country_Code], [1960], [1961], [1962], [2011])
VALUES
    ('IND', 'va11', 'va12', 'va13', 'va1x'),
    ('AUS', 'va21', 'va22', 'va23', 'va2x'),
    ('ENG', 'va31', 'va32', 'va33', 'va3x')

### ;

using unpivot conveting  columns to rows

select Country_Code, year, value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value 
  for year in ([1960], [1961], [1962], [2011])
) u

You can see demo from below link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ea3b